# Is it possible to allow user scripts while blocking anything else with uBlock Origin?

Tags: ublock-origin

In uBlock Origin there is the option to disable Javascript by default. I have that enabled:

[image: uBlock Origin default behavior]

However, this has one undesired effect. User scripts that I have installed will also no longer run. But while I am in control of the user scripts and therefore would like to enable them, I would like to continue blocking Javascript elsewhere by default.

How can I bridge that gap?

Comment: Maybe use dynamic filtering to block all scripts? Dunno how that interacts with user scripts.